# Send canvas data between applications

Tags: python, sockets, canvas, kivy

main.py

```
from kivy.base import EventLoop
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.graphics import Color, Line
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ToggleButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.togglebutton import ToggleButton
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.utils import get_color_from_hex
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.clock import Clock
CURSOR = (
    '       @@@@             ',
    '       @--@             ',
    '       @--@             ',
    '       @--@             ',
    '       @--@             ',
    '       @@@@             ',
    '                        ',
    '@@@@@@ @@@@ @@@@@@      ',
    '@----@ @--@ @----@      ',
    '@----@ @--@ @----@      ',
    '@@@@@@ @@@@ @@@@@@      ',
    '                        ',
    '       @@@@             ',
    '       @--@             ',
    '       @--@             ',
    '       @--@             ',
    '       @--@             ',
    '       @@@@             ',
    '                        ',
    '                        ',
    '                        ',
    '                        ',
    '                        ',
    '                        ',
)
class Update_Location(Widget):
    pass

class CanvasWidget(Widget):
    line_width = 2

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if Widget.on_touch_down(self, touch):
           return

        with self.canvas:
            touch.ud['current_line'] = Line(
                points=(touch.x, touch.y),
                width=self.line_width)

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        if 'current_line' in touch.ud:
            touch.ud['current_line'].points += (touch.x, touch.y)

    def set_color(self, new_color):
        self.last_color = new_color
        self.canvas.add(Color(*new_color))

    def set_line_width(self, line_width='Normal'):
        self.line_width = {
            'Thin': 1, 'Normal': 2, 'Thick': 4
        }[line_width]

    def clear_canvas(self):
        saved = self.children[:]
        self.clear_widgets()
        self.canvas.clear()
        for widget in saved:
            self.add_widget(widget)
        self.set_color(self.last_color)
    def start_server(self):
        host = '127.0.0.1'
        port = 5000
        notification_text="Server started on host: "+host+" and port: "+str(port)
        server_start=Popup(title='Notification',content=Label(text=notification_text),size_hint=(.75,.75),auto_dismiss=True)
        server_start.open()
        Clock.schedule_interval(server_start.dismiss, 3)


class PaintApp(App):
    def build(self):
        EventLoop.ensure_window()
        if EventLoop.window.__class__.__name__.endswith('Pygame'):
            try:
                from pygame import mouse

                a, b = pygame_compile_cursor()
                mouse.set_cursor((24, 24), (9, 9), a, b)
            except:
                pass
        #boxlayout
        self.layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')

        self.canvas_widget = CanvasWidget()
        self.canvas_widget.set_color(
            get_color_from_hex('#2980b9'))
        self.layout.add_widget(self.canvas_widget)
        #self.layout.add_widget(Label(text="Started Server : False , Connected to Server : False",color=(1,1,1),size_hint=(1, .1)))
        return self.layout

        #return self.canvas_widget


class RadioButton(ToggleButton):
    def _do_press(self):
        if self.state == 'normal':
            ToggleButtonBehavior._do_press(self)


def pygame_compile_cursor(black='@', white='-'):
    aa, bb = [], []
    a = b = 0
    i = 8
    for s in CURSOR:
        for c in s:
            a <<= 1
            b <<= 1
            i -= 1
            if c == black:
                a |= 1
                b |= 1
            elif c == white:
                b |= 1

            if not i:
                aa.append(a)
                bb.append(b)
                a = b = 0
                i = 8

    return tuple(aa), tuple(bb)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Config.set('graphics', 'width', '960')
    Config.set('graphics', 'height', '540')  # 16:9
    # Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', '0')
    # Config.set('input', 'mouse', 'mouse,disable_multitouch')

    from kivy.core.window import Window
    Window.clearcolor = get_color_from_hex('#ffffff')

    PaintApp().run()
```

server.py

```
import socket

def start_server(host,port):
    s = socket.socket()
    s.bind((host,port))

    s.listen(1)
    c, addr = s.accept()
    print "Connection from: " + str(addr)
    while True:
        data = c.recv(1024)
        if not data:
            break
        print "from connected user: " + str(data)
        data = str(data).upper()
        print "sending: " + str(data)
        c.send(data)
    c.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_server()
```

Above is the code for my simple paint application(adopted from kivy blue prints).

My aim is to start server on one application on localhost and then others connect to it. Those who can connected to it should get their canvas updated with one from the server they connected to. How can I send the data and update canvas. I have created a server in the above code using python's socket library.

I don't want to use http requests/threads instead establish connections with sockets and use async.io.

Comment: Have the server emit (maybe broadcast) JSON-ized canvas command objects.  Each command can be an index for the context command along with an array of parameters: `{i:0,p:[]}` where `i` is the index into a command array `var cmds=['beginPath',...]` and `p` is an array of any command parameters. Then you can use `context.apply` to execute the commands on the client.

Answer (score 4):

I created a quick REST flask service with a /canvas endpoint that supported post.  I also created a lines member of the CanvasWidget class to save how to recreate the data to send it to the server.  I had thought about doing pixel by pixel but I thought tracking the Line creation was more elegant and would support an undo redo feature if ever requested.

Directions

- Start server.py
- Start main.py
- Draw something
- Press the 's' key to send the current canvas to the server
- Quit the main.py application
- Start the main.py applicaion
- Press the 'r' key to receive the server's current state

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.base import EventLoop
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.graphics import Color, Line
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ToggleButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.togglebutton import ToggleButton
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.utils import get_color_from_hex
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.network.urlrequest import UrlRequest
import flask

CURSOR = (
    '       @@@@             ',
    '       @--@             ',
    '       @--@             ',
    '       @--@             ',
    '       @--@             ',
    '       @@@@             ',
    '                        ',
    '@@@@@@ @@@@ @@@@@@      ',
    '@----@ @--@ @----@      ',
    '@----@ @--@ @----@      ',
    '@@@@@@ @@@@ @@@@@@      ',
    '                        ',
    '       @@@@             ',
    '       @--@             ',
    '       @--@             ',
    '       @--@             ',
    '       @--@             ',
    '       @@@@             ',
    '                        ',
    '                        ',
    '                        ',
    '                        ',
    '                        ',
    '                        ',
)
class Update_Location(Widget):
    pass

class CanvasWidget(Widget):
    line_width = 2
    lines = []

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CanvasWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(self._keyboard_closed, self)
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)

    def _keyboard_closed(self):
        self._keyboard.unbind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)
        self._keyboard = None

    def _on_keyboard_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        if keycode[1] == 's':
            print 'send'
            json = flask.json.dumps(self.lines)
            req = UrlRequest('http://127.0.0.1:5000/canvas', req_body=json)
        elif keycode[1] == 'r':
            print 'receive'
            req = UrlRequest('http://127.0.0.1:5000/canvas', self.load_state)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if Widget.on_touch_down(self, touch):
           return

        with self.canvas:
            touch.ud['current_line'] = Line(
                points=(touch.x, touch.y),
                width=self.line_width)
            self.lines.append({'points':[touch.x,touch.y], 'width':self.line_width})

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        if 'current_line' in touch.ud:
            touch.ud['current_line'].points += (touch.x, touch.y)
            self.lines[-1]['points'].append(touch.x)
            self.lines[-1]['points'].append(touch.y)

    def set_color(self, new_color):
        self.last_color = new_color
        self.canvas.add(Color(*new_color))

    def set_line_width(self, line_width='Normal'):
        self.line_width = {
            'Thin': 1, 'Normal': 2, 'Thick': 4
        }[line_width]

    def clear_canvas(self):
        saved = self.children[:]
        self.clear_widgets()
        self.canvas.clear()
        for widget in saved:
            self.add_widget(widget)
        self.set_color(self.last_color)

    def load_state(self, req, results):
        print 'load_state req', repr(req)
        print 'load_state results', repr(results)
        #needs some validation here
        self.clear_canvas()
        with self.canvas:
            for line in results:
                Line(points=line['points'], width=line['width'])
        self.line = results 

    def start_server(self):
        host = '127.0.0.1'
        port = 5000
        notification_text="Server started on host: "+host+" and port: "+str(port)
        server_start=Popup(title='Notification',content=Label(text=notification_text),size_hint=(.75,.75),auto_dismiss=True)
        server_start.open()
        Clock.schedule_interval(server_start.dismiss, 3)


class PaintApp(App):
    def build(self):
        EventLoop.ensure_window()
        if EventLoop.window.__class__.__name__.endswith('Pygame'):
            try:
                from pygame import mouse

                a, b = pygame_compile_cursor()
                mouse.set_cursor((24, 24), (9, 9), a, b)
            except:
                pass
        #boxlayout
        self.layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')

        self.canvas_widget = CanvasWidget()
        self.canvas_widget.set_color(
            get_color_from_hex('#2980b9'))
        self.layout.add_widget(self.canvas_widget)
        #self.layout.add_widget(Label(text="Started Server : False , Connected to Server : False",color=(1,1,1),size_hint=(1, .1)))
        return self.layout
        #return self.canvas_widget


class RadioButton(ToggleButton):
    def _do_press(self):
        if self.state == 'normal':
            ToggleButtonBehavior._do_press(self)


def pygame_compile_cursor(black='@', white='-'):
    aa, bb = [], []
    a = b = 0
    i = 8
    for s in CURSOR:
        for c in s:
            a <<= 1
            b <<= 1
            i -= 1
            if c == black:
                a |= 1
                b |= 1
            elif c == white:
                b |= 1

            if not i:
                aa.append(a)
                bb.append(b)
                a = b = 0
                i = 8

    return tuple(aa), tuple(bb)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Config.set('graphics', 'width', '960')
    Config.set('graphics', 'height', '540')  # 16:9
    # Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', '0')
    # Config.set('input', 'mouse', 'mouse,disable_multitouch')

    from kivy.core.window import Window
    Window.clearcolor = get_color_from_hex('#ffffff')

    PaintApp().run()
```

server.py

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, json
app = Flask(__name__)

data = []

@app.route('/canvas', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def canvas():
    global data
    if request.method == 'GET':
        tmp = jsonify({})
        tmp.set_data(json.dumps(data))
        return tmp

    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = json.loads(request.data)
        tmp = jsonify({})
        tmp.set_data(json.dumps(data))
        return tmp


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Thanks so much!! Can you use buttons instead of keyboard presses. Using Flask seems a overkill, I would prefer python standard library if possible.

Comment: Yes you could use raw sockets for a client / server communication.  You'll have to support multiple clients trying to read from the same socket.  This isn't trivial and I was lazy and used flask to create a RESTful service.

Comment: I implemented your approach but it is not very scalable. Are there any solutions using say flasksocketio. So, you don't need to send request every time.